# Can we throttle API gateway with lambda function by IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to limit 100 requests per second for an IP using throttle. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: For IP throttling, you'll probably need WAF in front of api gateway.

Comment: Or consider [usage plans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) which requires API keys but then allows throttling by API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since API Gateway is triggered first & its before your main lambda you cannot control the Gateway from the lambda itself.

> But, API Gateway has a custom authoriser (Lambda authorizer) which is
> triggered first if enabled and once executed the request is passed to
> main lambda.

You can write the throttling code in lambda and attach that lambda as custom authoriser to API Gateway. This lambda can now approve or reject requests based on your throttling logic.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

However, a more straight forward solution will be using AWS WAF using which you can directly configure IP based throttling rule.

https://support.stackpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001380266-Create-a-Rate-Limit-Rule-with-the-WAF